# How to focus a specific row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which content binds from database. There are 3 column. Name,Address, Mobile. I have a text box for filter data of datadridview Name column. If I write "Sa" in text box gridview focus will be in Sa....... . Except "Sa" all data will present in datagridview but focus on "Sa...". How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code..

what we are doing here is whenever user type something into the textbox we iterate through each cell values of column index (0) and when a matching value is found we highlight that entire row.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Use could set the SelectionMode within FormLoad as well.
   dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

   dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

   foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
      if (item.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text))
      {
          item.Selected = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it might be faster when the value is being changed in textbox.

```
int j=dgv.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i+= 2)
{
    if (dgv.Rows[i].Cells["MyField"].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[i].Cells["MyField"];
        dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
        break;
    }
    if (j > -1 && dgv.Rows[j].Cells["MyField"].Value.ToString().Contains(txtSearch.Text))
    {
        dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[j].Cells["MyField"];
        dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = j;
        break;
    }
    j--;
}
```

`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` will scroll the grid to display that row at the first row of the grid display area.